# App to monitor changes performed by apps

Tags: android, monitoring, logs

As the title says, I'm looking for an Android app that **records EVERY changes that other apps perform on the phone**

Something like a log...

To see whatever the app writes on disk is my main goal; what files it changes; what files it creates (and directories, of course)

Does anyone know of any such app ?

Comment: Apps don't have the permission to view file system activity of other apps. Only on rooted devices this is possible. Using adb and root permissions you can use standard Linux Tool fsnotify-tools compiled for Android.

Comment: Hello. The root part is not a problem. Now, compiling things, that require other things, and learning how to work with it... My initial problem was not that complicated. Not an advanced user here. But I'm thankful for the effort of answering

Comment: If you use Termux environment from FDroid I am sure it has an installable package for fsnotify tools so you would not need to compile it yourself. And once installed you can use the tool from within adb, just the path into the Termux environment is a bit long...

Comment: ```~ $ pkg install fsnotify
Testing the available mirrors:
[...many links...]
Get:1 https://grimler.se/termux-packages-24 stable InRelease [14.0 kB]
Get:2 https://grimler.se/termux-packages-24 stable/main arm Packages [491 kB]
Fetched 505 kB in 5s (96.0 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
64 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
E: Unable to locate package fsnotify```

Comment: Error while installing. And that is the first part. I wonder what I'll meet on the *usage* part....  It was good to learn about this version of Termux, that I didn't, but I'm not sure my initial problem was worthy enough to go after fixing another before that. Always thankful, nonetheless

Comment: I think the package name is inotify-tools or something like this.

Comment: inotify-tools was found and installed successfully ✓✓. Any straight on usage tip ?

Comment: Sorry I haven't used this tool for years. But it doesn't has so much different options.